# Unable to access jBPM console

Tags: jbpm

I have just started with jBPM and new to BPM tools and have downloaded the jbpm-server-7.18.0.Final.zip, extracted into a local folder and run the command `./standalone.sh`. I am able to access the `localhost:8080/business-central` but not the http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console

I have not changed any settings, just used the package which is downloaded, Am I missing anything here?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!!

[image: jBPM Error]

Answer (score 1):

"jbpm-server-7.18.0.Final-dist.zip" seems to have only 3 web applications (business-central.war, jbpm-casemgmt.war, kie-server.war). So registered web contexts are.

```
Registered web context: '/kie-server' from server 'default-server'
Registered web context: '/jbpm-casemgmt' from server 'default-server'
Registered web context: '/business-central' from server 'default-server'
```

So "http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console" looks like an invalid URL. You can login to "localhost:8080/business-central" to access BPM functionalities and administration.